# Reversing the vowels of a string in python - Code is too inefficient

Tags: python

```
class Solution:
    def reverseVowels(self, s: str) -> str:
        indexes = []
        consonants = []
        vowels = []
        s2 = ""
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i].lower() in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]:
                indexes.append(i)
                vowels.append(s[i])
            else:
                consonants.append(s[i])
        for j in range(len(s)):
            if j in indexes:
                s2 += vowels[-1]
                del vowels[-1]
            else:
                s2 += consonants[0]
                del consonants[0]
        return s2
```

The above code is my solution.

Even though my code has an O(n) time complexity (I think), when I submitted the code, it passed 479/480 testcases and did not have enough time for the very last test case. It was a long string.

My code basically looks at every letter and checks if it is a vowel. If it is the vowel, it notes down the index. Otherwise, it takes it as a consonant, and adds it into the consonant array.

And then, it adds letters to a new string, s2, and it adds letters to it based on the indexes list. If the iteration matches one of the vowel indexes, it adds the last vowel in the list to the string, and removes that vowel. For consonants, it does something similar to that but with the first element.

I have tried to think about what I could cut down on in terms of loops and stuff, but I could not think of any way to make this more efficient. I would request you to try and help me find a solution that is more efficient than my current one.

Comment: There might be a lot to improve, but note that deleting the first item of a list is not cheap - it's O(n), not O(1) as you supposed (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582225/why-does-python-take-on-time-to-remove-the-first-element-from-a-list that includes a link to the documentation). Don't modify the list if you just need to iterate on it. Note also that checking if a value exists in a list is O(length of the list). Use a set instead of `["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is more pythonic to use `enumerate` rather than `range`. I have tried to keep the solution as close as your original attempt. You don't need to use `del` as it is expensive:

```
class Solution:
    def reverseVowels(self, s: str) -> str:
        str_index = []
        vowel = []
        res = []
        pos = -1
        for index, value in enumerate(s):
            if value.lower() in {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"}:
                str_index.append(-1)
                vowel.append(value)
            else:
                str_index.append(index)
        for index in str_index:
            if index < 0:
                res.append(vowel[pos])
                pos -= 1
            else:
                res.append(s[index])
        return ''.join(res)
```

Comment: Thanks mate, the enumerate helped me reduce the runtime significantly. Also, I didn't know that del was expensive haha, I thought it was O(1).

Comment: I think `enumerate` do not help in optimizing but the `del` was making it slow.